# Saying ***.cls file not found even if installed in the right directory to me

Tags: packages, compiling, installing

Impossible for me to compile a tex file because it's said ***.cls file not found even if the whole package directory is in usr/local/texlive/texmf-local on my mac

How to solve please?

Mactek installed. pdflatex not installed, ignoring how to install it.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you run `sudo mktexlsr` after installing the file in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`? Also, it should be saved as `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/<class>/<class>.cls` (where `<class>` stands for the file name).

Comment: Related: [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te)

Comment: @Schweinebacke : with TeX Live installed with MacTeX the personal tree has its root at `~/Library/texmf` (this is the `Library` folder in your HOMR folder, NOT the one in the root of you HD/SSD). Note: that folder is not created by the MacTeX installer. Note: you must create the structure yourself.

Comment: @HerbSchulz Joseph's answer or Dror's answer to the question I've linked in my comment already explicitly tells this.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your class is called `magox.cls`, you should issue, from the terminal and the work directory where you have either developed or downloaded the class, the following commands:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/magox
sudo cp magox.cls /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/magox
sudo mktexlsr
```

Change `magox` to the actual file name, of course.

Saving the class file directly in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` would not work, because LaTeX only looks (recursively) in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex`. Also `mktexlsr` is necessary, because otherwise the file would not be found in the cache that TeX Live maintains for reducing disk I/O.

After these operations, any document with `\documentclass{magox}` should work as expected.